# Hiding RichFaces Component on Radio Clicked in JSF using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, rendering

I am using JQuery with JSF+RF3.3
My requirement is that when a user clicks on the YES radio button few of the components will be shown. In case he clicks NO then those components will be hidden.
On page Load initially these components are shown.

Although using Jquery I am able to extract the value of the Radio Button Clicked I am not able to hide/show component.Morever the component is ListShuttle. I am not able to select any component in ListShuttle.The select itself is not working..

The code snippet is:-

```
<rich:panel>
<h:selectOneRadio id="Radio"  border="0" label="Name" value="#{bean.functionName}" required="true" styleClass="intro" onchange="showNameList()" >
<f:selectItem id="All" itemValue="All" itemLabel="All" />
<f:selectItem id="region" itemValue="Region" itemLabel="Region" />
</h:selectOneRadio> 
</rich:panel>
```

The components which will be shown/hidden on Radio Clicked are:-

```
    <div id="alll">
    <h:outputLabel value="RegionList *" id="region" styleClass="intro" escape="false" />
    <h:outputLabel value=" : " styleClass="intro" id="colonLabel" escape="false" />
    <h:panelGroup>    
    <rich:listShuttle id="calListShuttle" sourceValue="#{Bean.SourceList}" targetValue="#{Bean.targetList}" var="itemsRegion" fastOrderControlsVisible="false" orderControlsVisible="false" targetRequired="true" >
    <rich:column >

    <h:outputLabel value="#{itemsRegion}"/>
    </rich:column >                                 
    </rich:listShuttle>
</div>
```

The JQuery code is

```
<script>
    function showRegionList()
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
         {
        var $ = jQuery;

        $("input:radio[@name='Create\\:Radio']").click(function() { 
        var radioValue=$("input[name='Create\\:Radio']:checked").val();

        if(radioValue=="All")
        {
            $("#alll").hide("slow");    
        }
        else
        {
            $("#alll").show("slow");
        }

        });
         });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it under firebug or your favourite js debugger? Hide/show code looks fine and should work if it's reached. I am a bit lost with your jQuery.ready under showRegionList but I assume this part does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Actually I have never used firebug or js debugger...From now on I will surely try using it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making one fundamental mistake with jQuery. The jQuery library is designed to among others easily add event handlers to the HTML DOM tree during page load without the need to specify them yourself straight inside the HTML markup.

To get your code to work, you need to **remove** the event attribute from the markup:

```
onchange="showNameList()"
```

and you need to **remove** the function block around `jQuery.ready()`:

```
function showRegionList() {

}
```

*(those function names does by the way not match, please review your question carefully to avoid red herrings)*

This way the `jQuery.ready()` will run as intended and attach the `click` event handler functions to the desired HTML elements.

I strongly recommend to take some time apart to go through a bit decent jQuery book/tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the advice..There was a typo error as you pointed out.The problem I figured out was the inclusion of Jquery script hosted by Google.Since I am using RF3.3.3 which loads an internal JQuery 1.3.2 there was a conflict and hence none of the JSF components were working. When I loaded the RichFaces specific JQuery components started working but JQuery is not working.I guess I will have to use <rich:jQuery> tag to fire JQuery if I use RF and JQuery..

Comment: That's a different problem than you stated in the question.

Comment: My bad..This problem was solved when I loaded the JQuery script file which came with RichFaces.Some of the mistakes which you pointed out was also taken care of..Thanks again for your help...

Comment: A problem with this question still exists..The RichFaces component does not work..Either the Rf component works or JQuery works..Both do not work simultaneously. I have included the jquery script file which comes with RF3.3.3....